# Booting from ISO file without actually writing to CD or memstick

Tags: boot, iso

I want to test whether a certain ISO file is bootable. I could, of course, copy it to a memstick or DVD.  But I'd like to try booting it directly from the ISO file.  I realize that this will shutdown my running Kubuntu, but that's all right with me; I can easily restart it.

Is there an easy way to do this?  ("Easy" means easier than writing it out to a memstick and then loading the memstick.)

Answer (score 2):

Install virtualbox and boot the ISO from within virtualbox.